# Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-6

Tags: matlab

I'm doing this project about the Gauss-Seidel method to solve nodal voltages in the context of power system analysis.
However, in the line of

```
V(1,i) = (1/Y(i, i)) * (conj( S(1,i) / V(1,i) ) - Y(i, :) .* V(1, i));
```

I get the aforementioned error. I have seen other answers here, but in my specific case I can't seem to get this right for the life of me.

```
%admittance matrix
Y = [-6.8 + 1i*42.033 , -6.748+1i*36.725 , 0 , -0.0532+1i*5.29 , 0 , 0 ;
    -6.748+1i*36.725, -6.75+1i*42.09   , -0.08+1i*5.35, 0 , 0 , 0 ;
    0 , -0.08+1i*5.35 , -0.0795+1i*5.3497 , 0 , 0 , 0 ;
    -0.0532+1i*5.29 , 0 , 0 , -12.3428+1i*134.8 , -12.29+1i*129.2 , 0 ;
    0 , 0 , 0 , -12.29+1i*129.2, -0.265+1i*12.19763 , -0.26+1i*13.08 ;
    0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , -0.2654+1i*13.08 , -0.265+1i*13.079 ] ;
S2 = 0;
S3 = 150e6*(0.95 + 1i*sin(acos(0.95)));
S4 = 0;
S5 = 0;
S6 = 300e6*(0.95 + 1i*sin(acos(0.95)));
S = [0, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6];
% B) Gauss-Seidel method to solve for nodal voltages
V = [1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05]; % Initial guess
max_iter = 1000;
tolerance = 1e-6;

for iter = 1:max_iter
    
    for i = 2:6
        dVmax = 0;

        V_old = 1.05;

        V(1,i) = (1/Y(i, i)) * (conj( S(1,i) / V(1,i) ) - (Y(i, :) .* V(1,i)));
        dV = abs(V(i) - V_old );
        if (dV > dVmax)
            dVmax = dV;
            V_old = V(i);
        else
            V_old = V(i);
        end
    end
    if max(abs(V - V_old)) < tolerance
        break;
    end
display (V);
end
```

Comment: What of the title do you not understand? How can we help? Do you need explaining what the error means? Why it arises (likely that `Y(i,:)`)? or something else?

Comment: your error is here. 
this will be a 1-by-1 scalar: conj( S(1,i) / V(1,i) ). 
this will be a 1-by-6 vector: - Y(i, :) .* V(1, i).